# sqlite3.OperationalError - no column exists

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, schema

I am having an issue running a simple select statement within SQLite.

One of the columns in my database has "" quotes in its name. How would I go about selecting this column in my query?

Here's the table schema:

[image]

I've tried a variety of Select statements but no dice.

Here's my code so far:

[image]

Here's the error I'm running into:

[image]

What's the proper syntax to select this column: ["Address"]?

Comment: Use square brackets: `SELECT ["Address"],....`

Comment: Thank you for your quick response - I gave it a try and I got the same error: sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Address.

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite uses square brackets and double quotes as a way to denote that the enclosed text is an identifier ([docs](https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)).  However by using both, like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE (["Address"] TEXT...
```

the double quotes become part of the identifier.

If you want to use the column in a query you will need to put square brackets around the name *including* the double quotes, as they are part of the name, as seen in `Q1` in this script.

```py
import sqlite3    
    
DDL1 = """DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test"""    
DDL2 = """\    
CREATE TABLE test (    
 ["Address"] text)    
"""    
    
Q1 = """SELECT ["Address"] FROM test"""    
    
    
with sqlite3.connect('68132004.db') as conn:    
    cur = conn.cursor()    
    cur.execute(DDL1)    
    cur.execute(DDL2)    
    cur.execute(Q1)
```

However you can make your life easier by renaming the column using an `ALTER TABLE` instruction (the double quotes here signify that the enclosed text is an identifier):

```
DDL3 = """ALTER TABLE test RENAME COLUMN ["Address"] TO "Address" """    
    
Q2 = """SELECT Address FROM test"""    
    
    
with sqlite3.connect('68132004.db') as conn:    
    cur = conn.cursor()    
    cur.execute(DDL3)    
    cur.execute(Q2)
```

Or you could drop the table and recreate it without the doubly-identifier-quoted column name.